# Internet Explorer paste to Excel hang

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-excel, internet-explorer, copy-paste

One of my colleagues is having a trouble when copying data from our website to Excel. Excel freezes for 5-7 minutes (we timed it) before any data shows up. If using Paste Special / Values it's instant, but when doing a normal formatted paste it takes forever. Any ideas on how to solve this?

WinXP with Office 2007 Standard SP3

Comment: Sounds like it's trying to copy the formatting of what you've copied. I'd suggest to continue to copy - paste special values. You could write a macro for this and assign it a shortcut key

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with losing some formatting, you may want to try pasting to `notepad` first. then cut the data from notepad and paste that into Excel.

Comment: Problem is that end users can forget to do the special paste. If special paste can be set to be the default operation this wouldn't be a problem.